# Once swiping on UIImageView with animation the animation stops

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView with animationImages and it works fine

```
self.imageView.animationImages = [self loadImages];
self.imageView.animationDuration = 15;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```

I've added a swipe gesture that, in the selector of the swipe I want to do the following:

1. find the image that is currently shown
2. move to the next/previous image
3. continue the animation

Comment: First thing you can not stop images animation from Animation block either you have to remove that image yeah you need to create your custom animation using NSTimer/something else.

Comment: @iAmbitious do you mean instead of using startAnimating I have to write my own animation process?

Answer (score 0):

Post your gesture recognizer action method.

It will take some tinkering, but it should be possible to do what you want to do.

I suspect that you will have to stop the animation, juggle the order of the images in the animation array, and then start the animation again. The image view should revert to the normal content image when the animation stops, so you might want to set the normal image to the image on which you stop if you get flickering when you stop the animation and restart it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how can I get the current displayed image, when I use the animationImages with startAnimating the Image of UIImageView does not update, can you show me in code what you mean